# flowtype: how to annotate higher order function with parameter forwarding

Tags: flowtype

I have a function `foo`:

```js
function foo(a: string, b: string, c: number, d: boolean): Promise<Result> {
  return new Promise(resolver => {
    ...
  });
}

// use foo
foo('hello', 'world', 3, true).then(...);
```

and a higher-order function which take the function and then the parameters using currying:

```js
function hof(func: Function) {
  return async function (...args: any[]) {
    // forward the args to the func and get the result
    const result = await func(...args);
    // do something else with the result
  }
}

// use foo with higher-order function `hof`
hof(foo)('hello', 'world', 3, true);
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lack type annotations
```

How to use [flowtype](https://flowtype.org/) to annotate the whole part of the `hof` function:

- hof interface
- forwarding arguments `...args`: using `any[]` will lose the original types
- the return types for the currying function

Comment: BUMP ! Has anyone got a solution for this after 4 years? Currently hating life having to use Flow instead of Typescript for a job (just fyi Typescript has a concise and straightforward solution to this)..

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

I'm still looking for a better alternative but this is what is working for me so far:

```js
function foo(a: string, b: string, c: number): string {
  return 'Yay!'
}
// Alternatively, interface Arguments {
type Arguments = {
    <A>((A) => any): [A],
    <A, B>((A, B) => any): [A, B],    
    <A, B, C>((A, B, C) => any): [A, B, C],     
    <A, B, C, D>((A, B, C) => any): [A, B, C, D],
}

function hof <T: Function> (t: T): (...$Call<Arguments, T>) => void {
  return (...args) => undefined;
}

hof(foo);
hof(foo)("This", "works", 2);
// hof(foo)("this", "should't", "work");
// hof(foo)("Correctly", "fails", 2, "when there are extra args");
```

I was having a similar issue. That is, typing a function which takes a function with a specific set of arguments and returns a new function that takes the same set of arguments and I couldn't find a definite answer.

**Long version**

This is the result of researching flowtype issues and trial an error. [These are all the variations I tried that work in some degree](http://%20https://flow.org/try/#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-Jbq6g6-Xwi227gLSB0qNZFBe+3O056wOfCPLGPC61J2Bp+W5zXFwZ0rg4LuIL5GgeKFU28w2JxELrkR7I8fCMExzEsKocBAXB+HeAhlH-PUWBgAAPVMoh8Js8n-MB4VGOAijAbc8HYUxECgOA-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-6Lczpz2IAK2gxjKIM-J7qrhvyJAR2S6cjDhDBtvzcB+xx6dtEyRFHlFUFa5EAAH0FaEd731eMS33fSWFbk2VudGIvNXUOhX8-2SNHAo4txeJ4fzF2TJ9LqoKtn+TumZh8IIrMSqpxEGISqDkaogLqhuTmmZmp3wFg2dau4Oxdh7J+Xq+gKwdFQUuZs2DED1jXFxTc24MHiyPPgwhD4ny7jGiQr8pDrZvggE4H69IiyyHYk7Ug4RHrcxQQNesDDnxtmYb2VhS5KKvnfNwmUvD+GuBIEIts4BYAqUkppJIqYrYsR-BwOOAEzBwHyDASgTtALCJAsYfWlgSgvUsHJUwVtKIcD4hYmC1iS6UU8HdUer9AbsUoEoHOMFSBjwnhtPUsgiTqCHELNxLAPEVxLixXAGAWjeXyG7RCiAwDmWHBwpwsFY67S0vBHOYAsgnGLIBbQs8iTvxsUqC4RIT6XCJBQLpB9OmnD6UM-k3TBlKGGRM-kkyr4Y1vsAEoMVWlL3YGlCmf8qbgIFLAkgoCAGlUgcDKqOz4w5SKQgrmyCFmEPQW2TB3YZG4NnNcsRI1dzkI3FuHcdyaELV1CUehj5JGkOkZ+Ya8iylKJ9FAPhN01FCJ1voPW4FEAAFZbDJOVrBJie14LQHtk5Hi6QIAbmsl5Hy3MAhBBCPLSIMQ4gJCSCkPmGRsi5HyUUUolRaj1EKE0IsnRui9AGMMHwcszriTbsYWCEga7WSRPUmQ-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-HkxXMyZZfRWMo77P2IgQN+4qf6r2ahC2xI2rN-RnKDCGMMUDGYbMKtBsEsGvqpi5oe5rOHAtXLKNsbAoa6DkCoDgZlTsTjwI1PeIF6qHkUEIIUAc3glsEeITRs7fZaG6jW68u7lGKHUZ+bRp7wAXtMZY3FNjHGpFcZYbx1w-H4ThyE7Yo8gXD1DkUKoRAAB1fc7ETihnKWAUMAEWDODznJXM8JtDCCAA)

```js
function foo(a: string, b: string, c: number): string {
  return 'Yay!'
}

// Attempt 1:
// Taken from 
// https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4672#issuecomment-377649789

declare function arguments<A>((A) => any): [A]
declare function arguments<A, B>((A, B) => any): [A, B]
declare function arguments<A, B, C>((A, B, C) => any): [A, B, C]
declare function arguments<A, B, C, D>((A, B, C, D) => any): [A, B, C, D]
type Arguments<T> = $Call<typeof arguments, T>

function hof1 <T: Function> (t: T): (...Arguments<T>) => void {
  return (...args) => undefined;
}

const augmentedFn = hof1(foo)("This", "works", 2);
// const augmentedFn2 = hof1(foo)("this", "should't", "work");
// const augmentedFn2 = hof1(foo)("Also", "check", 2, "number of args");

// Attempt 2: using array of mixed.
// This one doesn't seem to have limit to the arguments you can provide,
// but it doesn't seem to fail when extra args are passed.
// Notice that the return type is specified in the function signature

function hof2 <T: Array<mixed>>(func: (...T) => any): (...args: T) => any {
    return (...args) => null;
}

hof2(foo)("2", "2", 1);
// hof2(foo)(1, "this fails correctly", 1);
hof2(foo)("2", "2", 1, "This one has extra arg, but this method can't  limit them");

// If we define the generic return type in the returned function, flow breaks
function hof2broken <T: Array<mixed>>(func: (...T) => any) {
    return (...args: T) => null;
}
// hof2broken(foo)("This should work", "but fails with a cryptic message", 1);

// Attempt 3, using generics to capture the tuple values.
// It requires us to declare one generic for each arg in any function
// that uses them. Notice that I have to redeclare all the A, B, C and D generic
// types just to pass them to the tuple type.

type genericTuple<A, B, C, D> = [A] | [A, B] | [A, B, C] | [A, B, C, D]

function hof3<A, B, C, D, T: genericTuple<A, B, C, D>>(func: (...T) => any): (...args: T) => any {
  return (...args) => null;
}

hof3(foo)("This", "works", 2);
// hof3(foo)("this", "should't", "work");
hof3(foo)("Also", "fails", 2, "to check the argument's length");
// hof3(foo)("Also", "fails", 2, "to check the argument's length", "until it exceeds the number of possible args");

// Attempt 4
// It seems to be possible to ommit the generics by using tuples of 'any'
// This seems to have the same issues of not checking for extra unwanted args

type anyTuple = [any] | [any, any] | [any, any, any] | [any, any, any, any]

function hof4<T: anyTuple>(func: (...T) => any): (...args: T) => any {
  return (...args) => null;
}

hof4(foo)("This", "works", 2);
// hof4(foo)("this", "should't", "work");
hof4(foo)("Also", "fails", 2, "to check the argument's length");

// Attempt 5:
// Trying to extract the type calculated in 
// https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4672#issuecomment-377649789
// without getting redeclaration warnings
// This works in the 'try' console, but doesn't in the 0.80.0 version
// in Mac OS, so I can't stick with it
// I think that this working on the 'try' console is probably a bug

type ArgsFrom<T> = $Call<
  (<A>((A) => any) => [A]) &
  (<A, B>((A, B) => any) => [A, B]) &
  (<A, B, C>((A, B, C) => any) => [A, B, C]) &
  (<A, B, C, D>((A, B, C, D) => any) => [A, B, C, D]), T>

// type Arguments2<T> = $Call<argtest, T>  

function hof5 <T: Function> (t: T): (...ArgsFrom<T>) => void {
  return (...args) => undefined;
}

let testVar = hof5(foo);
hof5(foo)("This", "works", 2);
// hof5(foo)("this", "should't", "work");
// hof5(foo)("Correctly", "fails", 2, "when there are extra args");

// Attempt 6: I read somewhere that overloading is supported
// on interfaces, so I gave it a try. It seems to work and I will stick with it.

type Arguments3 = {
    <A>((A) => any): [A],
    <A, B>((A, B) => any): [A, B],    
    <A, B, C>((A, B, C) => any): [A, B, C],     
    <A, B, C, D>((A, B, C) => any): [A, B, C, D],
}

function hof6 <T: Function> (t: T): (...$Call<Arguments3, T>) => void {
  return (...args) => undefined;
}

hof6(foo);    
hof6((a: string, b: boolean) => null)("Also works", true); 
hof6(foo)("This", "works", 2);
hof6(foo)("this", "should't", "work");
hof6(foo)("Correctly", "fails", 2, "when there are extra args");

// Yay! Works and kind of makes sense
```